# Bootstrap menu toggle not working with multiple toggle links

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a functional side navigation that toggles in and out of display. Here is the "Filter" button...

```
<a href="#menu-toggle" style="background-color:black; color:white;" class="btn btn-default page-header" id="menu-toggle">
   <span style="position:relative; top:2px; right: 5px;"class="glyphicon glyphicon-resize-horizontal"></span>
                        Filter</a>
```

and the JQuery...

```
<script>
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    });
</script>
```

When I add another clickeable link to toggle the same menu it breaks down but I can't understand why? I've changed the menu-toggle id to a class but that didn't help.

Here is the code that doesn't work i.e. the second clickable link that should give the same toggle effect...

```
<li class="sidebar-brand">
     <a href="#" id="menu-toggle">Collapse
     </a>
</li>
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the code above works; however, if you add another side-navigation anchor, the code fails. If that is correct, please add the code which is failing. Otherwise, please provide more information (and code) that may help to describe the problem.

Comment: @Pred I've added the failing code. Thanks!

Comment: @SurajKapoor, can you include the second toggle link, possibly the `#wrapper` too

Comment: Post all your code to check dependencies and so on, this should works

Comment: @SurajKapoor: you have two elements with the same id ("menu-toggle"). Your script will see the first element and ignore the second element, causing it to fail.

Comment: Maybe it's because you have multiple tags with the same id "menu-toggle" ! Try to change it with different id a give it a class name.

Comment: I tried changing id to a class - this makes the second link active but the first one becomes inactive.

Comment: @SurajKapoor: You would need to also change the first element from having an id of "menu-toggle" to a class of "menu-toggle". Then the class selector will catch both elements.

Comment: @Pred both elements were changed from id to class :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a class instead of an ID for multiple elements being operated on.

```
$(".menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
});
```

Change `<a id="menu-toggle"></a>` to  `<a class="menu-toggle"></a>`

Comment: Hi Brian, see my comment above. I tried this earlier and it makes the second link active but the first one inactive!

Comment: Hi, I tried adding it to JsFiddle but it's complicated since there are frameworks and I've never used Fiddle before. Anyway, you can see the HTML here - http://talenthack.herokuapp.com/companies/. This is without the second link (which I want to go under "Hiring: Business"). Hopefully this will give you a clearer picture!

Comment: Be sure you're removing the previous click function, and infact changing the classes to IDs (The HTML needs to change to classes as well as the jQuery selector).. I just tested the above solution and it works.

Comment: I tested my solution on the link provided, if implemented correctly it will work for the questioners purposes.. but you are free to post you're own solution :)

Comment: You are right. I've been staring at this for way too long. I did this... class="btn btn-default page-header" class="menu-toggle", and it should be class="btn btn-default page-header menu-toggle". Thanks for your help!!